# Android internal autoscaling feature only for large screens

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

i am developing a game with canvas. I want use the Android internal
autoscaling feature (anydensity=false;) only for large density
screens. Is it possible to enable this graphics (in the drawable
folder) scaling function only for large screens. For smallscreens my
Game Engine does automatically manage the presentation.

I attempted the following in the manifest.xml:

```
<supports-screens
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="false"
 android:anyDensity="false" />
```

.. but it doesnt work, Android does also downscale the graphics for smallScreens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using imageviews, maybe you could use [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) and use the value 0 (for matrix) and use the identit matrix to keep the image at its original size.